# How do I make a slideshow survey with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm wanting to make a survey like this: https://takecareof.com/survey/new in vue. I don't need any of the animations I just want the slideshow part. I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Please try to show us what you've done. Please follow guidelines https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way will be **programmed routing**. First you ask name then route to the next component which greets for that name and so and so.

https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: Great idea! The asker didn't specify if he's using router, so I presented a simpler abordation.

Answer (score 0):

For a basic slideshow in vue, you could try the following:

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <nav class="slide-nav">
    <div 
       v-if="currentSlide > 0" 
       v-on:click="currentSlide--" 
       class="prev-slide">
      <i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>
    </div>
    <div 
       v-if="currentSlide < slides.length-1" 
       v-on:click="currentSlide++" 
       class="next-slide">
      <i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="slide">
    <h2>{{slides[currentSlide].title}}</h2>
    <div class="slideContent" v-html="slides[currentSlide].content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    slides: [
        {
          title: 'Title 1',
          content: `<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>`
        },
        { 
          title: 'Title 2',
          content: `<p>Donec porttitor, <strong>ligula ut finibus efficitur</strong>, magna sapien eleifend sapien, accumsan consequat magna elit a leo.</p>`
        },
        { 
          title: 'Title 3',
          content: `<p>Vestibulum condimentum, neque ut tristique luctus, mi mauris egestas tellus, sed tincidunt tortor mi sed ante.<br>Donec purus ipsum, auctor et volutpat ut, aliquet id magna.</p>`
        }
    ],
    currentSlide: 0
  }
})
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/hfoletto/pen/aGVRZM

The Title and content object of each slide is hold by the `slides` array data property.
Initializing the `currentSlide` property as 0 makes the default slide the first one.

In the HTML, [conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) does the trick for only showing the prev button if the `currentSlide` property is more than 0 (aka first slide) `v-if="currentSlide > 0"` and the next button only when the currentSlide is lower than index position of the last object in the `slides` array: `v-if="currentSlide < slides.length-1"`

Using the `v-on:click` [event handler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) in the prev and next buttons, we can add or decreases 1 of the `currentSlide` property, so the content reactively changes.

Note: I'm using [ES6 Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) here, but you don't have to.

I highly encourage you to take a deep dive into the [Vue js Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/), it's really straight forward!

If you want to add some animations, check out the [Transitions & Animations Vue Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html).

Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended that you try [Vueper Slides](https://antoniandre.github.io/vueper-slides/#examples).
Easy to use slideshow for Vue JS with more features.

You just need this markup:

```
<vueper-slides>
  <vueper-slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :key="i" :title="slide.title" :content="slide.content"></vueper-slide>
</vueper-slides>
```